# How to display angular mat-grid-list without skewing list- overflow?

Tags: angular

I want 2 columns display, so using mat-grid-list and mat-grid-tile

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7kuvr?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts

This stackblitz skews the first list. This is unwanted.  This example is to show that, if the list is large, it should not cut.

Actual Aim: Output like this - 2 columns display
[image]

But not 1 below another - https://stackblitz.com/angular/roapnkprbxl?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html

[image]

**Please can you help how to avoid skewing  + display in 2 column format**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try implementing the `mat-grid-list`as seen [here](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview)?
I recently used this component and didn't get the highlighted experience (although I didn't run it in stackblitz). It just renders as a 2-column table in my browser, which is what I believe you want to achieve.

Here is a glimpse into what my code looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="productService.productForm" class="normal-form" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="350px" gutterSize="20px">
    <mat-grid-tile>
      <div class="controles-container">
        
         ---some `mat-form-fields`---

      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>

    <mat-grid-tile>
      <div class="controles-container">

        ---another group of `mat-form-fields`---

      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</form>
```

...and for the styling:

```
.normal-form {
  margin: 0 40px 20px 40px;
}

.controles-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
}

.controles-container > * {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.